# Apache spark streaming kafka API vs kinesis API

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, spark-streaming, amazon-kinesis, spark-streaming-kafka

I am having an scala spark application in which I need to switch between streaming from kafka vs kinesis based on the application configuration.

Both the spark API's for kafka streaming (spark-streaming-kafka-0-10_2.11) and kinesis streaming (spark-streaming-kinesis-asl_2.11) returns an `InputDStream` on creating a stream, but the value types are different.

Kafka stream creating returns `InputDStream[ConsumerRecord[String, String]]`,
whereas, Kinesis stream creating returns `InputDStream[Array[Byte]]`

Is there any `API` that returns a generic `InputDStream` irrespective of kafka or kinesis, so that my stream processing can have a generic implementation, instead of having to write separate code for kafka and kinesis.

I tried assigning both the stream to a `InputDStream[Any]`, but that did not work.

Appreciate any idea on how this can be done.

Comment: You could have Kafka return a `ConsumerRecord[Array[Byte], Array[Byte]]`, but the fact you get one binary blob from Kinesis and a Record object from Kafka can't really be applied in generics

Comment: That makes sense, thanks for the comment.